# What does the "きゃ" in "していきゃがらなかった" stand for?

Tags: slang

I read this phrase in a visual novel:

"こいつが出かける前に、きっちり支度をしていきゃがらなかったからじゃねぇかっ！？"

I don't get what the "きゃ" means in this context. If it's short for "ikeba", I can't make sense of "がらなかった" ("didn't show any signs" of what? ) and if it's something different, I don't have a clue.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41333/9831

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「していき**ゃ**がらなかった」 with a **small** ゃ

The "dictionary" form of that is:

> 「していき**や**がらなかった」 with a regular-size や

The components are 「する」、「行{い}く」、「やがる」 and 「なかった」.

For an explanation of 「Verb + やがる」, please read:

[How to use the inflection "やがる"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4236/how-to-use-the-inflection-%e3%82%84%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8b)

Thus, the sentence in question is in the Kanto tough guy speech.

> "That's because this dude hadn't made proper preparations before leaving (home), ain't it?"

I didn't make it sound too tough, did I?